# unable to sort varchar type data in the integer way?

Tags: sql-server, ado.net

I have a table `purchase` with a column `po_no` of `varchar` data type.

In the column data is saved in the format of `1/14-15`, `98/14-15`, `99/14-15`, `100/14-15`.

I need to sort my data as sequence like `98/14-15`, `99/14-15`, `100/14-15`.

Please help me out how to do it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Purchase
(
    po_no VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL
)
ON [Primary];

INSERT INTO dbo.Purchase (po_no)
VALUES
    ('100/14-15'),
    ('98/14-15'),
    ('1/14-15'),
    ('99/14-15');

SELECT po_no,
        CAST(SUBSTRING(po_no, 1, CHARINDEX('/', po_no) - 1) AS SMALLINT) AS 'v1',
        CAST(SUBSTRING(po_no, CHARINDEX('/', po_no) + 1, CHARINDEX('-', po_no) - CHARINDEX('/', po_no) - 1) AS SMALLINT) AS 'v2',
        CAST(SUBSTRING(po_no, CHARINDEX('-', po_no) + 1, 99) AS SMALLINT) AS 'v3'
    FROM dbo.Purchase
    ORDER BY v1, v2, v3;
```

Results are:

```
po_no        v1     v2     v3
------------ ------ ------ ------
1/14-15      1      14     15
98/14-15     98     14     15
99/14-15     99     14     15
100/14-15    100    14     15

(4 row(s) affected)
```

Or you can omit displaying the variables and just sort by them:

```
SELECT po_no
    FROM dbo.Purchase
    ORDER BY CAST(SUBSTRING(po_no, 1, CHARINDEX('/', po_no) - 1) AS SMALLINT),
        CAST(SUBSTRING(po_no, CHARINDEX('/', po_no) + 1, CHARINDEX('-', po_no) - CHARINDEX('/', po_no) - 1) AS SMALLINT),
        CAST(SUBSTRING(po_no, CHARINDEX('-', po_no) + 1, 99) AS SMALLINT);
```

Results are:

```
po_no
------------
1/14-15
98/14-15
99/14-15
100/14-15

(4 row(s) affected)
```

Comment: It is sorting data, but some cases it is error. Like " The conversion of the varchar value '987605' overflowed an INT2 column. Use a larger integer column."

Answer (score 0):

1. cut your string until first /
2. convert string to integer
3. sort by that integer

Comment: It is sorting data, but some cases it is error. Like " The conversion of the varchar value '987605' overflowed an INT2 column. Use a larger integer column."